# Query system load from R

Tags: r, rserve

Is there a way from R to be able to query a Linux OS and determine the number of active processes and/or CPU utilization?  For example, the `top` command returns useful information to answer this, however `system` in R doesn't return a value that I can interact with, it just prints the `STDOUT` and moves on.

I'm working with Rserve behind a load balancer and I'd like to double check the load balancer is putting me on a server without excessive load.

Comment: @r2evans would you add this as an answer?  It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `system2("cat", "/proc/loadavg", stdout = TRUE)` (see `?system2` for more info). (This is obviously just an example ... the key is adding `stdout=TRUE` to whatever command you are using.)